# Attribution requirements for Google Translate

Tags: google-translate

I wish to use the results of the Google translation that results from right clicking on a web page in Chrome, as opposed to using the API. These results I will use as part of a web language learning tool. I have read this page: https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution about adding a logo, and have also read the HTML markup requirements at https://cloud.google.com/translate/markup.

My question is as these terms and conditions pages are referring to the API, do they also apply to using the translation results of using the Chrome menu item? I could use the API but this is much simpler for my temporary need.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, when you're using the Google Translate Tool in a page by using the right-click, you can see that it send a request to the Google Translate API.

In definition, you have to add Google Attribution.

I guess for a personal website or non-commercial use it might not be that big of an issue but still, it will avoid future ones.

[image]